# Which of these two sentences is right and why?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, sentence-structure, questions

I have some problems with making sentences. For example, I don't know which one of the following sentences is right.

> What devil's action had you done?
>
> What devil's action you had done?

> this period of time that mentioned here.
>
> this period of time which is mentioned here.

> I might don't accept it.
>
> I might not accept it.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? For example, have you Googled **I might don't**?

Comment: Actually, I used the Grammarly app, and there was no problem.

Comment: If I Google it I find 6 examples. But If I Google **I might not** I get 20 *pages* of examples.

Comment: If you have known the answer, you will answer at least one part of my question.

Comment: The Tour (https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) might be a good place to start.

Comment: It will be good for you too.

Comment: I've answered question 3 :-)

Comment: Yes, but just in your mind.

Comment: Seriously, Grammarly gave no recommendation for that third example?? Then I must say the tool is plain dumb. Also as OldBrixtonian said, you must have at least searched on Google. The definition of [might](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/might) makes it clear why two, and why not one. Also be respectful and polite to other members here. If you do not benefit by what they say, do not respond harshly to it.

Comment: Yes, It didn't suggest any corrections. Don't you think it is better to give an answer instead of giving advice? My question has other parts too. I've searched for it and I know the 2nd one is right but I don't know why the first one is wrong.